# Gspread and python on windows mobile or windows CE

Tags: python, windows-mobile, windows-ce, gspread

I am working on an inventory project for work that will use a mobile computer and have run into a problem. I have written a program using Python and the Gspread library, but forgot to check if it will even work with either the windows mobile or windows CE operating systems. From what I have found there is a version of python for Windows CE but I am not sure if the Gspread library even works with this version of python.

Has anybody had any experience working with these operating systems or does somebody have a better understanding of python and its libraries? can I just install a library into any version of python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although gspread source code is available and a python modul it depends on urllib and that depends on various other modules that are not part of PythonCE.

So, I fear, you will not success in getting gspread running on the windows mobile device.

Best solution to this seems to use a web server that hosts the html pages. Apache, for example, can host python code.

OTOS gspread is a warpper for google spread sheet API that can be invoked directly from html javascript code running on windows mobile device. But does a spread sheet make sense on such small displays?

Comment: hmmm... thats too bad. I will look into what you suggested thank you.

Yeah the python code was supposed to work around the fact that using spreadsheets on a small display is not effective. it just requests the item count and updates the spreadsheet accordingly.